# Firebase Cloud Function not showing error message

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

The title is self explanatory. I have added an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeDMP.png). This function is written in javascript, I can provide it if needed

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I want to know why firebase is not displaying the error message, not why my code is not working. The code is working, but It is slow and I Just want to know If its an issue with firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after toggling around, I found out this error occurs when Firebase is capping your funciton execution time, so I solved it by upgrading my plan to Blaze